# When should I just use "int" versus more sign-specific or size-specific types?

Tags: c, unsigned, signed

I have a [little VM for a programming language](https://github.com/munificent/wren) implemented in C. It supports being compiled under both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures as well as both C and C++.

I'm trying to make it compile cleanly with as many warnings enabled as possible. When I turn on `CLANG_WARN_IMPLICIT_SIGN_CONVERSION`, I get a cascade of new warnings.

I'd like to have a good strategy for when to use `int` versus either explicitly unsigned types, and/or explicitly sized ones. So far, I'm having trouble deciding what that strategy should be.

It's certainly true that mixing them—using mostly `int` for things like local variables and parameters and using narrower types for fields in structs—causes lots of implicit conversion problems.

I do like using more specifically sized types for struct fields because I like the idea of explicitly controlling memory usage for objects in the heap. Also, for hash tables, I rely on unsigned overflow when hashing, so it's nice if the hash table's size is stored as `uint32_t`.

But, if I try to use more specific types *everywhere*, I find myself in a maze of twisty casts everywhere.

What do other C projects do?

Comment: I stick with int (for the reasons it was invented for: natural machine size) unless there is good reason not to. Some of them have been named by others. I'm amazed that you want to control your struct sizes. So little memory? Or so many structs? Plus: Without packing the structs, chances are fields will be padded anyway to int size (because that's the natural size).

Comment: Btw, I really appreciated the effort to eliminate warnings and your corresponding "RFC".

Comment: Using specific types is perhaps more important on small embedded systems. For example, see [this post](http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2011/02/efficient-c-tip-13-use-the-modulus-operator-with-caution/) on Efficient C Tips.

Comment: I, too, have yet to find an acceptable solution to this gnarly issue. On common platforms where most everything is a 32-bit word you can largely forget about it but when frequent type mixing is required for performance things get messy fast. My one firm conclusion to date is that implicit type coercion warnings do more harm than good _as long as the only weapon for acknowledging them are explicit casts_. Admittedly I do have the luxury of generally not writing safety-critical software and can live with the odd integer overflow bug..

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica `int` is often NOT the natural machine size. `int` needs to be at least 16 bit, many machines do have a natural integer size of 8.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 The meaning of "often" is a bit nclear -- I suppose that most 8-bit architectures would be microcontrollers. They may be more common in number but not necessarily be more common in terms of what most programmers use.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Most C programmers i know in real live do also program for 8-bit controllers. If you want natural machine size integer, use `uint_fast8_t`, some machines may have even shorter natural sizes, but there is no better choice in C because C requires at least 8 bit per addressable object.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Re "Most C programmers i know": I guess we all (me included, of course) live in our specific bubbles of experience. But the [stackoverflow survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020#most-popular-technologies) states "for the eighth year in a row, JavaScript has maintained it's stronghold as the most commonly used programming language", followed by HTML, SQL, Python, Java, Shell, C#, PHP and TypeScript. None of those run on 8 bit controllers. C is at 11th position with 24%, and only a minority of that deals with controllers.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica The Question is about C. By the way, struct sizes are not the main reason to chose the type correctly, the type reflects meaning. Using `int` shows the intend is to store values that can be negative, that may don't fit in 8 bit, that it was (hopefully) made sure the value can't exceed either `32767` or `INT_MAX`. Using `int` almost everywhere shows me that someone didn't think about which data type to choose and it worries me that the code can run into UB because someone just used `int` without thinking about it or its limits.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Ah, true, we were only discussing C programmers. In all fairness, I don't know many of those at all (C++ was used on all "large" embedded systems I was developing or testing for). Yes, within the C community there is certainly a larger share of controller programming.

Answer (score 34):

Just using `int` everywhere may seem tempting, since it minimizes the need for casting, but there are several potential pitfalls you should be aware of:

- **An `int` might be shorter than you expect.**  Even though, on most desktop platforms, an `int` is typically 32 bits, [the C standard only guarantees a minimum length of 16 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1738591).  Could your code ever need numbers larger than 2<sup>16</sup>−1 = 32,767, even for temporary values?  If so, don't use an `int`.  (You may want to use a `long` instead; a `long` is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits.)
- **Even a `long` might not always be long enough.**  In particular, there is no guarantee that the length of an array (or of a string, which is a `char` array) fits in a `long`.  Use `size_t` (or `ptrdiff_t`, if you need a signed difference) for those.

  In particular, [a `size_t` is defined to be large enough to hold any valid array index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174850/type-for-array-index-in-c99), whereas an `int` or even a `long` might not be.  Thus, for example, when iterating over an array, your loop counter (and its initial / final values) should generally be a `size_t`, at least unless you know for sure that the array is short enough for a smaller type to work.  (But be careful when iterating backwards: `size_t` is unsigned, so `for(size_t i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)` is an infinite loop!  Using `i != SIZE_MAX` or `i != (size_t) -1` should work, though; or use a `do`/`while` loop, but beware of the case `n == 0`!)
- **An `int` is signed.**  In particular, this means that [`int` overflow is undefined behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is)  If there's ever any risk that your values might legitimately overflow, don't use an `int`; use an `unsigned int` (or an `unsigned long`, or `uintNN_t`) instead.
- **Sometimes, you just need a fixed bit length.**  If you're interfacing with an ABI, or reading / writing a file format, that requires integers of a specific length, then that's the length you need to use.  (Of course, is such situations, you may also need to worry about things like endianness, and so may sometimes have to resort to manually packing data byte-by-byte anyway.)

All that said, there are also reasons to avoid using the fixed-length types all the time: not only is `int32_t` awkward to type all the time, but forcing the compiler to always use 32-bit integers is not always optimal, particularly on platforms where the native `int` size might be, say, 64 bits.  You *could* use, say, C99 `int_fast32_t`, but that's even more awkward to type.

---

Thus, here are my personal suggestions for maximum safety and portability:

- **Define your own integer types for casual use** in a common header file, something like this:

  ```
  #include <limits.h>
  typedef int i16;
  typedef unsigned int u16;
  #if UINT_MAX >= 4294967295U
    typedef int i32;
    typedef unsigned int u32;
  #else
    typedef long i32;
    typedef unsigned long i32;
  #endif
  ```

  Use these types for anything where the exact size of the type doesn't matter, as long as they're big enough.  The type names I've suggested are both short and self-documenting, so they should be easy to use in casts where needed, and minimize the risk of errors due to using a too-narrow type.

  Conveniently, the `u32` and `u16` types defined as above are guaranteed to be at least as wide as `unsigned int`, and thus can be used safely without having to worry about them being [promoted to `int` and causing undefined overflow behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27001604/32-bit-unsigned-multiply-on-64-bit-causing-undefined-behavior)
- Use `size_t` for all array sizes and indexing, but be careful when casting between it and any other integer types.  Optionally, if you don't like to type so many underscores, `typedef` a more convenient alias for it too.
- For calculations that assume overflow at a specific number of bits, either use `uintNN_t`, or just use `u16` / `u32` as defined above and explicit bitmasking with `&`.  If you choose to use `uintNN_t`, make sure to protect yourself against unexpected promotion to `int`; one way to do that is with a macro like:

  ```
  #define u(x) (0U + (x))
  ```

  which should let you safely write e.g.:

  ```
  uint32_t a = foo(), b = bar();
  uint32_t c = u(a) * u(b);  /* this is always unsigned multiply */
  ```
- For external ABIs that require a specific integer length, again define a specific type, e.g.:

  ```
  typedef int32_t fooint32;  /* foo ABI needs 32-bit ints */
  ```

  Again, this type name is self-documenting, with regard to both its size and its purpose.

  If the ABI might actually require, say, 16- or 64-bit ints instead, depending on the platform and/or compile-time options, you can change the type definition to match (and rename the type to just `fooint`) — but then you really do need to be careful whenever you cast anything to or from that type, because it might overflow unexpectedly.
- If your code has its own structures or file formats that require specific bitlengths, consider defining custom types for those too, exactly as if it was an external ABI.  Or you could just use `uintNN_t` instead, but you'll lose a little bit of self-documentation that way.
- For all these types, don't forget to also define the corresponding `_MIN` and `_MAX` constants for easy bounds checking.  This might sound like a lot of work, but it's really just a couple of lines in a single header file.

Finally, remember to be careful with integer math, especially overflows.
For example, keep in mind that the difference of two *n*-bit signed integers may not fit in an *n*-bit int.  (It will fit into an *n*-bit *unsigned* int, if you know it's non-negative; but remember that you need to cast the inputs to an unsigned type *before* taking their difference to avoid undefined behavior!)
Similarly, to find the average of two integers (e.g. for a binary search), don't use `avg = (lo + hi) / 2`, but rather e.g. `avg = lo + (hi + 0U - lo) / 2`; the former will break if the sum overflows.

Comment: "Define your own integer types for casual use", sounds horrible practice. Code littered with custom types is harder to understand and maintain. Even you yourself might forget what types you used earlier, let alone a new developer working on the code, and then you have same things with different types.

Comment: @hyde I am no expert (far from it) but I work at a medium sized company (~200 people) which develops software which needs to run on anything from various cloud solutions, to desktops, to our own embedded systems. It is our experience that as soon as you need to compile you code for anything but desktop computes compilers are not to be trusted. C may guarantee 16 bits for an int but in some, very constrained environments, that's just not fulfilled. You are correct that it took me some time to get used to, but manually typedef-ing everything is the way we have found to write portable code

Comment: @Markus: The point is that the standard explicitly defines `<stdint.h>` and `<inttypes.h>`, with standard typedef's of `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t` etc. etc. for just that purpose. Including the appropriate `_MIN` and `_MAX` definitions and everything.

Comment: @hyde: You're right, having every developer in a shared project defining their own types would be a nightmare. That's *not* what I was trying to suggest. Rather, you only define *one* set of appropriate types for your project(s), in a single header file, and document those types as part of your group's code style conventions document (which every new developer is required to read).

Comment: @DevSolar: Those types are very useful, and I personally use them a lot, but they do have some drawbacks (and not just being awkward to type). Notably, there's no guarantee that, say, a `uint32_t` value won't get silently promoted to a signed (64-bit) `int` in arithmetic expressions on some platforms, which could mess up any code expecting standard 32-bit unsigned overflow behavior. Also, arithmetic using those types might be needlessly inefficient, as compared to just using (`unsigned`) `int`. [...]

Comment: [...]  The custom `i32` and `u32` types I suggested above are essentially like the C99 `int_fast32_t` and `uint_fast32_t`, except that they're easier to type, and [actually guaranteed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395590/is-uint-fast32-t-guaranteed-to-be-at-least-as-wide-as-int) to be at least as wide as an `int`, and thus not subject to integral promotion.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen In most software projects, multiple libraries are used. And, IMO, even inside a single project, lot of code should be organized in reusable libraries. Consistent use of custom typedefs tends to start to fall apart over time. But the word I am most critical there is *casual*. Custom typedefs of basic types is IMO for non-casual, special use.

Comment: @hyde: Not if you're writing portable code. If you're only targeting platforms where, say, `int` is at least 32 bits wide (which, notably, includes all POSIX systems), then sure, just use `int`. But if you intend your code to also run on embedded systems where `int` is only 16 bits wide, then I'd say *don't* use `int`, especially not in a shared project, because *someone's* going to assign 100,000 to an `int` sooner or later. Either use fixed-size types (but beware of integral promotion, as noted), use `long` for everything (safe but suboptimal), or use custom types like `i16` and `i32` above.

Comment: you could use Preprocessors to replace `int` into the next best primitive data-type based on OS & architecture

Comment: Hmmm `avg = lo + (hi + 0U - lo) / 2` has its troubles too.  Try `int lo = 1;   int hi = 0; printf("%u %d\n", lo + (hi + 0U - lo) / 2, (lo + hi) / 2);`  But then I guess the not so clear assumption is that `hi >= lo`.  Otherwise - stellar answer.

Comment: I should add the 2 average formulas are equivalent when `0 <= lo <= hi`.  `lo + hi <= INT_MAX` needs to hold true for the simple formula, but not your improved one.  Recommend dropping the average formulas as they detract from the answer for they need to much qualification.

Comment: When I see a type called something like `u16`, I assume that a struct containing two such values will be the same size as one `u32`; if you mean `unsigned int`, then call the type something like `uint`.

Comment: How do your `i32` and `u32` types not subject to integral promotion? Sure they are, when used in expressions containing larger integer types. I don't see how they are an improvement to that at all.

Comment: @Ilmari so where does your `i32` type come in, in that example? I guess I'm missing something in your statements or I am misunderstanding what you are saying.

Comment: @Ilmari that's what I thought. They don't solve the problem at all. The real solution is using the correct types everywhere, be it ad hoc typedef's or standard types.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74945/discussion-between-rubenvb-and-ilmari-karonen).

Comment: @rubenvb: Promotion of e.g. a 16-bit `unsigned short` to a 32-bit `int` would be harmless on compilers whose generated code for 32-bit `int` values would always yield results which, even in case of overflow, would be correct mod 65536. Most two's-complement compilers do that naturally with all `int` math, and even compilers for sign+magnitude machines may omit any logic that would care about overflow in cases where the result is being stored to an `unsigned short` [whether or not the standard would require them to omit such logic, it's a simple optimization].

Comment: @rubenvb: I do think C would benefit greatly from having a set of non-promotable modular-arithmetic types [so that e.g. the sum of two 16-bit values of such a type would be another], but I don't think the default promotion rules are "stupid". They mean that a compiler with eight integer types and two floating-point types will only need to define three (for two's-complement machines) or five (for other machines) ways to e.g. multiply two numbers, rather than having to define ten of them.  For a compiler that's trying to run in less than 64K, I'd say that's a good thing.

Comment: Calling a type `u16` that is not always 16 bit is a horrible idea.

Comment: The problem is having to type _t all the time.  In this situation typedefs are fine as long as you only use them for that purpose (uint32_t becomes uint32) .  If you dislike hungarian notation then this is easily justified.

Answer (score 15):

You seem to know what you are doing, judging from the linked source code, which I took a glance at.

You said it yourself - using "specific" types makes you have more casts. That's not an optimal route to take anyway. Use `int` as much as you can, for things that do not mandate a more specialized type.

The beauty of `int` is that it is abstracted over the types you speak of. It is optimal in all cases where you need not expose the construct to a system unaware of `int`. It is your own tool for abstracting the platform for your program(s). It may also yield you speed, size and alignment advantage, depending.

In all other cases, e.g. where you want to deliberately stay close to machine specifications, `int` can and sometimes should be abandoned. Typical cases include network protocols where the data goes on the wire, and interoperability facilities - bridges of sorts between C and other languages, kernel assembly routines accessing C structures. But don't forget that sometimes you would want to in fact use `int` even in these cases, as it follows platforms own "native" or preferred word size, and you might want to rely on that very property.

With platform types like `uint32_t`, a kernel might want to use these (although it may not have to) in its data structures if these are accessed from both C and assembler, as the latter doesn't typically know what `int` is supposed to be.

To sum up, use `int` as much as possible and resort to moving from more abstract types to "machine" types (bytes/octets, words, etc) in any situation which may require so.

As to `size_t` and other "usage-suggestive" types - as long as syntax follows semantics inherent to the type - say, using `size_t` for well, *size values* of all kinds - I would not contest. But I would not liberally apply it to anything just because it is guaranteed to be the largest type (regardless if it is actually true). That's an underwater stone you don't want to be stepping on later. Code has to be self-explanatory to the degree possible, I would say - having a `size_t` where none is naturally expected, would raise eyebrows, for a good reason. Use `size_t` for sizes. Use `offset_t` for offsets. Use `[u]intN_t` for octets, words, and such things. And so on.

This is about applying semantics inherent in a particular C type, to your source code, and about the implications on the running program.

Also, as others have illustrated, don't shy away from `typedef`, as it gives you the power to efficiently define your own types, an abstraction facility I personally value. A good program source code may not even expose a single `int`, nevertheless relying on `int` aliased behind a multitude of purpose-defined types. I am not going to cover `typedef` here, the other answers hopefully will.

Comment: "... not liberally apply it (`size_t`) to anything just because it is guaranteed to be the largest type."  Hmmm  confident `size_t` is not guaranteed to be the largest type.  Certainly large enough for indexing, but not necessarily the largest integer type.  `uintmax_t` is a better candidate for largest type.

Comment: @chux: Indeed it is not. In fact it is frequently insufficient even for indexing, think traditional x86 far pointers and the equivalent constructs on modern 8/16-bit embedded systems.

Comment: @doynax: In any memory model other than `huge`, no single object can exceed 64K; while a 16-bit `int` would be dubious for a ptrdiff_t, there is no problem using a 16-bit `unsigned int` for a `size_t` since indexing outside the range of an object would be Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @supercat: You're right of course, I was conflating `far` and `huge`. Truth be told I've been tinkering with embedded systems lately and haven't touched segmented x86 assembly in more than a decade.

Comment: @doynax: IMHO, the segmented architecture of the original 8086 is a thing of beauty, but for two problems: (1) there aren't enough segment registers, and there are a few "missing" instructions like load seg,immed or a "use immediate segment" prefix; (2) languages don't really know how to deal with it.  If the 80386 had included a mode which was just like real mode except that segment registers were 32 bits, scaled by a factor of 16 as with the 8086, such mode would have been awesome for things like the JVM or .NET.  In exchange for enforcing a 16-byte alignment on objects...

Comment: ...one would be able to access 64GB of address space using 32-bit references (which would only take half as much cache space as 64-bit references).  If the top 3 bits or so of the segment could select one of 8 segment groups, each with its own base address and scale factor, then .NET could partition the address space into 8GB of small-object heap with 8-byte alignment, 256GB of medium-object heap with e.g. 256-byte alignment, and 4TB of large-object heap with 4KB alignment, while continuing to use 32-bit object references.  Unfortunately, C has no data type for "segment-aligned pointer".

Comment: @supercat  It's been a while but i thought 386 had a similar thing to 086 segment registers, in the form of paging and memory swapping registers etc.

Comment: @LegendLength: The 80286 and 80386 designs require the existence of a segment descriptor associated with each different segment value, and the 80386 design is limited to 16-bit segment value.  If one were trying to design a 16-bit object-oriented VM on the 8086 analogous to the Java VM (but for 16-bit system) and didn't mind padding all object sizes to multiples of 16 bytes, the 8086 design would allow segment values to be used directly to identify objects, but such a design would be impractical on any of the later processors.

Comment: @supercat Almost seems like it could work with a smart compiler.  Just take the large objects and put them in the align16 area, the rest go in normal addressed memory.

Comment: @LegendLength: It could work in languages that distinguish between the pointer to the start of a large array (which might be required to have an alignment coarser than the individual elements) versus pointers to the elements thereof, but wouldn't really work well in C.

Comment: @LegendLength: Another interesting note about the 80386, btw: if one has a segmented/offset pointer `p` stored in e.g. ES and DI, and wants to store `(uintptr_t)p` somewhere, the most efficient way of doing the store would only write 48 bits.  The Standard would allow an implementation to document that the top 16 bits from such a conversion would have Unspecified values, but that could make things work strangely.  If segment registers could have been treated as 32 bits wide, the resulting 64-bit segment+offset pointers would be easier to work with than 48-bit ones the 80386 actually used.

Answer (score 8):

Keep large numbers that are used to access members of arrays, or control  buffers as `size_t`.

For an example of a project that makes use of `size_t`, refer to [GNU's dd.c, line 155](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/coreutils/src/dd.c#155).

Comment: The links are good, yet recommend include more of a synopsis of them _here_ as links too often break.

Comment: Link is broken: 404 Not Found

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things I do.  Not sure they're for everyone but they work for me.

1. Never use `int` or `unsigned int` directly.  There always seems to be a more appropriately named type for the job.
2. If a variable needs to be a specific width (e.g. for a hardware register or to match a protocol) use a width-specific type (e.g. `uint32_t`).
3. For array iterators, where I want to access array elements 0 thru n, this should also be unsigned (no reason to access any index less than 0) and I use one of the fast types (e.g. `uint_fast16_t`), selecting the type based on the minimum size required to access all array elements.  For example, if I have a `for` loop that will iterate through 24 elements max, I'll use `uint_fast8_t` and let the compiler (or stdint.h, depending how pedantic we want to get) decide which is the fastest type for that operation.
4. Always use unsigned variables unless there is a specific reason for them to be signed.
5. If your unsigned variables and signed variables need to play together, use explicit casts and be aware of the consequences.  (Luckily this will be minimized if you avoid using signed variables except where absolutely necessary.)

If you disagree with any of those or have recommended alternatives please let me know in the comments!  That's the life of a software developer... we keep learning or we become irrelevant.

Comment: If code needs to e.g. perform mod-4294967296 multiplication of two `uint32_t` values, I know of no remotely-clean portable way to express that without using type `unsigned`.  I would further suggest that unsigned types be avoided in contexts not involving modular arithmetic because given `uint32_t a=1,b=2;` some platforms will regard a-b as -1 and others will regard it as 4294967295.  If one wants modular arithmetic, one should cast the result to `(uint32_t)`, but if one doesn't I'd suggest avoiding types that may perform it.

Answer (score 0):

Always.

Unless you have specific reasons for using a more specific type, including you're on a 16-bit platform and need integers greater than 32767, or you need to ensure proper byte order and signage for data exchange over a network or in a file (and unless you're resource constrained, consider transferring data in "plain text," meaning ASCII or UTF8 if you prefer).

My experience has shown that "just use 'int'" is a good maxim to live by and makes it possible to turn out working, easily maintained, correct code quickly every time. But your specific situation may differ, so take this advice with a bit of well-deserved scrutiny.

Comment: "What do..." You're quoting something I didn't say, so I'm not sure how to respond. May I help here?  "Always...? What the...? Good. You're questioning my answer. You have critical thinking. Since you ask "what the..." I'll just say that my view on "int" isn't the universal view, and it might not even be the most popular, but I know I'm not alone.  Some say use "unsigned" when you're sure it's not a value intended to be negative, but all you gain is one bit, and invite more pain than that's worth. My way simply allows writing clear correct code quickly. I'm out of chars to comment more.

Comment: Sheesh.. what a system. I re-read the question and realized your "What do.." part is part of the original poster's question. I tried to edit my answer, but *6* minutes went by, and you only get *5*. Anyway, I was responding to the question in the title: "When should I just use int?" with "Always... unless...", not the body "What do other C projects do?" You can deduce what I do in my C projects from my answer, and decide for yourself what to do with it (use it or not--it's just one of several ways of looking at it).

Comment: Interesting--got my first down-vote here from somebody out there. No explanation why. Seems to me there are varying opinions on this matter, and no right answer. Even if I think mine is the right answer, I wouldn't down-vote the folks who say you should always use the more bit-specified types (although working with their code tends to drive me a little crazy.. for( uint_fast16_t i = 0 ...). Oh well...

Comment: Bad idea, `int` is signed and can cause the problems signed integers can cause in C. If you access an array, never use `int`, use `size_t` or, when you know more about the maximum array size, you can use `int_fastN_t` or a other unsigned type. Always think about the possible data ranges a variable needs and choose the type accordingly. You should not assume an `int` can store values greater than 32767 outside of `#if INTMAX>32767`, do not blindly assume `int` is 32, on many platforms a `int` is 16 bit. If you want to store values >32767, use a type that reflects that such as `uint_fast32_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, using `int` is not ideal. The main reason is that `int` is signed and signed can cause UB, signed integers can also be negative, something that you don't need for most integers. Prefer unsigned integers. Secondly, data types reflect meaning and a, very limited, way to document the used range and values this variable may have. If you use `int`, you imply that you expect this variable to sometimes hold negative values, that this values probably do not always fit into 8 bit but always fit into `INT_MAX`, which can be as low as `32767`. Do not assume a `int` is 32 bit.

Always, think about the possible values of a variable and choose the type accordingly. I use the following rules:

- Use unsigned integers except when you need to be able to handle negative numbers.
- If you want to index an array, from the start, use `size_t` except when there are good reasons not to. Almost never use `int` for it, a `int` can be too small and there is a high chance of creating a UB bug that isn't found during testing because you never tested arrays large enough.
- Same for array sizes and sizes of other object, prefer `size_t`.
- If you need to index array with negative index, which you may need for image processing, prefer `ptrdiff_t`. But be aware, `ptrdiff_t` can be too small, but that is rare.
- If you have arrays that never exceed a certain size, you may use `uint_fastN_t`, `uintN_t`, or `uint_leastN_t` types. This can make a lot of sense especially on a 8 bit microcontroller.
- Sometimes, `unsigned int` can be used instead of `uint_fast16_t`, similarly `int` for `int_fast16_t`.
- To handle the value of a single byte (or character, but this is not a real character because of UTF-8 and Unicode sometimes using more than one code pointer per character), use `int`. `int` can store `-1` if you need an indicator for error or not set and a character literal is of type `int`. (This is true for C, for C++ you may use a different strategy). There is the extremely rare possibility that a machine uses `sizeof(int)==1 && CHAR_MIN==0` where a byte can not be handled with a `int`, but i never saw such a machine.
- It can make sense to define your own types for different purposes.
- Use explicit cast where casts are needed. This way the code is well defined and has the least amount of unexpected behaviour.

After a certain size, a project needs a list/`enum` of the native integer data types. You can use macros with the `_Generic` expression from C11,  that only needs to handle `bool`, `signed char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long` and their `unsigned` counterparts to get the underlying native type from a typedefed one. This way your parsers and similar parts only need to handle 11 integer types and not 56 standard integer (if i counted correctly), and a bunch of other non-standard types.